# Using tasks when they have all completed

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, scheduled-tasks, task

[image]I have a question about the Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll method

Here is my code:

```
private void CheckNewResult(){
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(TasksList.toArray(),CompleteTasks);
}
private void CompleteTasks(Tasks[] tasks)
{
 if(tasks.Any(t => t.Status == (TaskStatus.RantoCompletion)))
 {
    //do something
 }
}
```

My question is when is the Complete Tasks method actually called? Is it when all the tasks have finished completing their requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing this

```
 Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(TasksList.toArray(),CompleteTasks);
```

Documentation states that

> Creates a continuation Task that will be started upon the completion of a set of provided Tasks. Either in completed state or any other.

One possible approach is to test the status of the task, and only attempt to perform continuation if the status is not Faulted or Canceled. So you need to do this.

```
 if(tasks.Any(t => t.Status == (TaskStatus.RantoCompletion)))
```

Comment: Ok, I am still at little confused because I purposely made it so two tasks would have a status of faulted and  in the debugger when I get to tasks.Any all the tasks are in the list and there are some that are faulted and ran to completion. So im thinking ContinueWhenAll has nothing to do with their status because in the debugger it passes it with no problem and in real time?

Comment: I doubt that See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus.aspx

Comment: @DeVonte Just loop through each Task and debug the status to see what are their statuses.

Comment: what is the result of this statement  if(tasks.Any(t => t.Status == (TaskStatus.RantoCompletion))). True or false?

Comment: If you look in the window at the bottom it shows the task array that was passed into the Complete Tasks method and at that moment there are still some that is faulted and some that has ran to completion

Comment: it is true because some of the tasks have ran to completion if I change it to tasks.all it will not be true anymore

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd321473.aspx):

> Creates a continuation Task that will be started upon the completion
>   of a set of provided Tasks.

Yes, it's called when *all* tasks were finished.

Comment: so does that mean theres no need for the statement: if(tasks.Any .... because we already know that everything is completed by that time.

Comment: @DeVonte: I would say no.

Comment: @Tigran How will he then check that all the tasks have completed? He needs to alter the statement to check the completion of all tasks anyhow.

Comment: @EhsanUllah the reason why I have task.any instead of task.all is because of the program I am using and some may come back faulted. Unless you have another method that I can possibly use.